# WebRTC iOS Media Constraint for Audio Only Call

Tags: ios, audio, webrtc

I am working on iOS Webrtc and want to make Audio only call with Audio Only SDP

I am creating Offer as bellow but SDP still has audio and video in it

What is the correct way to create AUDIO only offer

```
NSDictionary *mandatoryConstraints = @{
                                       @"OfferToReceiveAudio" : @"true",
                                       @"OfferToReceiveVideo" : @"false"
                                       };

RTCMediaConstraints* constraints =
[[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints
                                      optionalConstraints:nil];
```

Comment: How do you create the offer ? It cannot generate an audio SDP without a microphone attached to the PeerConnection.

Comment: @AxelIsouard Thanks u gave me a hint and I resolved the issue. In new version of WebRTC they changed something so mentioned parameters are accepted so I changed the implementation after your hint and now I create Video Sender only when Video Calling is set to enabled

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this.

1. Create your peerConnection with those constraints
2. Create an AudioTrack
3. Create a MediaStream, add the audio track to the MediaStream
4. Add the MediaStream to your peerConnection
5. Create the offer and send to the receiver

On the receiving side, you do the reverse

Comment: I had implement same steps but Only video streaming is working. Audio is not working for other user. Is there any way to trase audio is receiving or not.

Answer (score -4):

I am able to find the solution by creating Video Sender only if video is enabled as below.

```
if (_videoAllowed) {
    [self createVideoSender];
}
```

Comment: This is not solution.